# JSON-RPC to SOAP and back to JSON: Mapping JSON objects to non-trivial SOAP messages

Tags: java, web-services, scala, soap, esb

I'm trying to create a server that takes JSON-RPC requests from a client, transforms those into non-trivial SOAP requests to a SOAP server, then takes the SOAP response and sends the client a transformed JSON response. The responses that come back from the SOAP server are potentially very complicated and nested, and I'm trying to map the XML fields to flatter JSON. The mappings wont be 1:1. As an example, we may get back a sequence of codes in the SOAP response that we want to return in the JSON response as their values from a database.

I'm willing to use whatever languages or technologies are best appropriate, so is there anything out there that already solves this problem or can help?

Comment: similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26490929/custom-transform-rest-to-soap-to-rest-using-apache-camel

Answer (score 0):

scalaxb can turn SOAP into case classes and interfaces. [lift-json](https://github.com/lift/framework/tree/master/core/json) can turn case classes into json.

The scalaxb-generated code would be 1:1. See [wsdl 1.1 support](http://scalaxb.org/wsdl-support).

If you want to map the case classes into some other intermediate case classes, you can do that first. Then you can apply lift-json to turn them into json automatically

```
scala> import net.liftweb.json._
scala> import net.liftweb.json.Serialization.{read, write}
scala> implicit val formats = Serialization.formats(NoTypeHints)
scala> val ser = write(Child("Mary", 5, None))
scala> read[Child](ser)
res1: Child = Child(Mary,5,None)
```

or manually

```
scala> import net.liftweb.json._
scala> implicit val formats = DefaultFormats // Brings in default date formats etc.
scala> case class Child(name: String, age: Int, birthdate: Option[java.util.Date])
scala> case class Address(street: String, city: String)
scala> case class Person(name: String, address: Address, children: List[Child])
scala> val json = parse(...)
scala> json.extract[Person] 
res0: Person = Person(joe,Address(Bulevard,Helsinki),List(Child(Mary,5,Some(Sat Sep 04 18:06:22 EEST 2004)), Child(Mazy,3,None)))
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on how that would work? Wouldn't the mapping [still be 1:1](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/JSON_Support)?