# Custom Transform REST to SOAP to REST using Apache Camel

Tags: json, web-services, soap, apache-camel, esb

We are building an utility which will :

1. Accept JSON through a RESTful service
2. Map it to a POJO
3. Transform it to an Object which can be used to call a remote SOAP service (JSON is not identical as SOAP-XML, for example a few fields are missing, so we got to map entities instead of doing automation.)
4. Make a SOAP API call, and fetch the result.
5. Transform this result to JSON and send it back to client.
   (Process are synchronous to avoid complexity initially).

**Plan A**: We successfully tried Mulesoft Anypoint studio to build the flow. It provides Data Mapping, where we can easily map members from JSON to SOAP stub, and transform results again to JSON.

**Plan B**: Due to licensing constraint in Plan A, I am planning to do it using Camel. I am quite new to it, but could successfully build POC web app, which exposes a servlet accepting JSON. But now I am stuck as I don't know how to transform and call a remote soap. (WSDL is available).

**Intended Flow**

Client -> (Camel starts here) RESTful service -> Transform data -> Remote SOAP -> Accept response and transform to JSON -> Send back to client.

Any pointer into the right direction will be helpful.

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: @Namphibian For mule esb, i tried Anypoint studio and was successful doing it.  For camel based approach, i couldnt find proper one. So implementing via DSL/Spring

Comment: I am working a tutorial about apache camel and eclipse ide maybe it can help check out namphibian.blogspot.com. The tutorial is incomplete should be done end of week but maybe it is usefull. I will be able to help you a bit more when I get home in transit at the moment.

Comment: @Namphibian which tool you are using for visual ?

Comment: Eclipse Kepler and JBoss Fuse plugin. Follow the second and third part of the blog and you will be able to do it.

Comment: @navaltiger , wondering if you manage to do this. I know it is quite late now. j I am trying to do exactly the same. I am non java background so finding it difficult where to start. However, i did basic example of examples using blueprint but that won't solve my problem, finding it a bit tedious . Do you have any github or any example i can start with. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your main problem is JSON<->SOAP transformation. You can use `**freemarker**` component as producer and write transformation logic in freemarker template language. Below is a sample JSON to SOAP transformation using FTL

```
<#ftl encoding="utf-8">
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:iser="http://example.com/service" xmlns:das="http://example.com/service">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <iser:header>
         <iser:username></iser:username>
         <iser:password></iser:password>
         <iser:agency>${body.customer.name}</iser:agency>
      </iser:header>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <iser:readCompositeAddressByAddressNum>
         <iser:arg1 addressNum="${body.customer.addressNum}" buildingCode="0" cityCode="0" districtCode="0" quarterCode="0" streetCode="0" streetTypeCode="0" townshipCode="0" villageCode="0">
         </iser:arg1>
      </iser:readCompositeAddressByAddressNum>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

save above as **inputTransformer.ftl**. Create your output transfomer ftl (SOAP to JSON) and use both in your interface like below

```
from("direct-vm:getCustomerDetail")
.routeId("getCustomerDetail")
..
..
.to("freemarker:inputTransformer.ftl")
.log('{$body}')
.to(<Your SOAP Service>)
..
..
.to("freemarker:outputTransformer.ftl")
.log('${body}')
```

Send the transformed json back to your rest caller.

Hope it helped.